# Changing compilation debug to false in the web.config file in an asp.net application is giving me the page isnt redirecting properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I changed the compilation debug from true to false and now when I try to access the site, I get the error page isnt redirecting properly. The site is wrapped in SSL and it is deployed with debug = true and works fine but after doing some research I learned that it should be debug = false.

The error description is that the webpage redirects you in an endless loop. I am going to the home page and I dont know where the endless loop is coming from.

Comment: Not to sound silly, but can you debug it to find out?  We can't see any code, any configuration, anything.  So we can't really help.  It sounds like the release build on the server fails in this way, but the debug build does not.  Does a release build on the local machine also fail?  It might yield more information.  Additionally, you can put logging statements in your code to narrow down where the problem happens in a production environment.

Comment: Not enough info. Server side - attach debugger and see what is happening, client side - look on requests (i.e. using Fiddler).

Comment: I am very new to this so bare with me and thanks for your immediate reply. If you set debug to false, how do you debug the application. The application works fine in debug mode. On the local machine I can access all the pages except the login one because it redirects to https instead of http and I assumed that was the problem locally but on the live I cant access any page. I will check Fiddler and get back to you.

Comment: I used fiddler and I noticed I was getting 302 found. I enabled customErrors in the config file but still got the same thing. Would a screen shot from fiddler help? The weird thing I noticed is that when debug mode is ON under host you see tunnel to and url is the www.domainname.com:433 while when debug mode is off I see under host www.domainname.com and url: default.aspx. Btw I didnt provide any code because I have no idea where the problem is since the application runs fine with Debug mode on.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Thanks for the help. Since I didnt write the application I assumed that the logic was correct. Never assume anything I guess. Someone disabled the ssl in the code and no one had a problem before because debug was enabled all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change any file in hosted web app, IIS drops application pool and with it all session states. So if you are storing something in the session oyour change may trigger some logic in your application when you are relying on session variables.

Comment: Thank you for the help you inspired me to look at the code that I found the problem in.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell a root cause, but you should try setting the deployment retail=true which keeps you from having to change the web.config and does other 'production' changes as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228298(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I will take a look in doing that. Thanks.